# Flip a div using a timer

Tags: jquery, flip

I have a square DIV(300px x 300px) that I want to flip every 5 seconds using a timer. I want to use the [jQuery flip plugin](http://lab.smashup.it/flip/) to accomplish this. Here's what I have so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/psivadasan/4dPaX/3/

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Firstly you need to work on your fiddle your link doesnt have jquery set, and doesnt load the flip plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't including any libraries in your jsfiddle so it's not going to work. But the basic idea is to put the flip code inside an interval:

```
var $flipBox  = $('#flipbox'),
    flip_opts = [{
        direction: 'tb',
        bgColor: '#FFFFF',
        color: '#000000',
        speed: 500,
        content: "Hello World!"
    },
    {
        direction: 'tb',
        bgColor: '#FFFFF',
        color: '#000000',
        speed: 500,
        content: "Goodbye World!"
    }],
    curr_indx = 0,
    timer     = setInterval(function () {
        if (curr_indx >= flip_opts.length) {
            curr_indx = 0;
        }
        $flipBox.flip(flip_opts[curr_indx]);
        curr_indx++;
    }, 5000);
```

The `flip_opts` variable is an array of objects, each object is a set of options to be passed to the flip plugin. This code will go through each set of options in order and then loop back to the beginning.

If you want to stop the interval you can call: `clearInterval(timer);`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I included jQuery and the flip plugin in jsfiddle and pasted your code from above and it doesn't seem to work. Here is the link:
http://jsfiddle.net/psivadasan/4dPaX/5/

Comment: @Prasant You weren't including the jQuery UI library (which is required) and you can't link directly to files in github. I added the jQuery UI library and pasted the flip plugin code directly into jsfiddle and it works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/4dPaX/6/

Comment: You can choose the `raw` output from github which makes the URL look like this: https://raw.github.com/roncioso/Flip-jQuery/master/jquery.flip.js

Comment: Thanks Jasper for the jsfiddle code and how to link on github!

Answer (score 2):

No matter *what* you want to run periodically in JavaScript, you can use `setInterval`.  In the case of your flip code:

```
setInterval(
    function() {
        $('#flipbox').flip({
                    direction: 'tb',
                    bgColor: '#FFFFF',
                    color: '#000000',
                    speed: 500,
                    content: "Hello World!"
                });
    },
    5000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried using this code and it does change the content inside the DIV but does not flip. Would you know why the flip isn't happening?

Comment: great...at some interval it flips..thnx